# Python - Dataframe Output Support

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I have a pair of functions that work to create Linear Regression Group By column ClientID.
I have two dataframes; dfTotal3, dfWeightComp. dfTotal3 is the complete data set and dfWeightComp is an aggregate table which generates the target for each ClientID.

This first function creates the Linear Regression, the second function groups by ClientID

```
def model(dfTotal3, target):
    y = dfTotal3[['Steps']].values
    X = dfTotal3[['WeightDiff']].values
    return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, y).predict(target))

def group_predictions(df, target):
    target = dfWeightComp[['DTWDG']].values
    return dfTotal3.groupby('ClientID').apply(model, target)

dfLRSteps = group_predictions(dfTotal3, dfTotal3['DTWDG'])
```

The output given looks like:

```
ClientID
AB00001    [22378.285131195335, 21297.06927617608, 21315....
AB00002    [20483.8305898491, 18159.833358735963, 18199.3...
AB00003    [22623.58584474885, 19964.634731382826, 20009....
AB00005    [15635.423214285713, 14758.849920443217, 14773...
dtype: object
```

The above is a single object and I have been unsuccessful converting into a dataframe, I am also unsure why there is more than one value produced for each ClientID
I was hoping to return a dataframe, with only one 'prediction' as there is only one 'target' for each ClientID

| ClientID | Prediction |
| --- | --- |
| AB00001 | 22378 |
| AB00002 | 20484 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated